# Is there a way to listen to button click events or know when a user has clicked a button in an externally loaded script?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, iframe

I have a react application that wishes to implement an external script and html button from a platform which contains button that triggers a script that pops out an iframe for checkout. I added this external script in my React index.html file and rendered the button in a component. When that button gets clicked, it calls that script. It is working but I would like to know when user checks-out by listening to their button click. I dont know if this is possible. Or any way to know when user perform certain action such as clicking check out button;
Here is the script:

```
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.wetravel.com/widgets/embed_checkout.js"></script>
</body>
```

I added the button in a component:

```
<button class="wtrvl-checkout_button" id="wetravel_button_widget" data- 
env="https://awebsite.com" data-version="v0.3" data-uid="62302" data- 
uuid="54806750" href="https://website.com/checkout_embed?uuid=54806750" 
style={{backgroundColor:'black', color:'#ffffff', border: '0px', borderRadius: '5px', 
fontFamily: 'Poppins', cursor: 'pointer'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the pages being served form the same origin (`scheme://hostname:port`) or the listened to page has a [Access Control Allow Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) permitting your origin? Is the page where the clicks are happening launched (`window.open`) from the page listening? If both are true then yes it’s possible.

Otherwise it’s a hard no. Huge security hole.